# SP en EF no retorna todos los datos C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente SP que me retorna una lista de datos.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ListaClientesMante] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT C.ID_Cliente, C.Cliente, C.Direccion, K.Tipo_Cliente, C.Telefono, L.userName, E.Correo
    FROM dbo.Cliente C WITH(INDEX(Cliente_pk))
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Login L ON L.userName=C.ID_Usuario
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CorreoCliente E ON E.ID_Cliente=C.ID_Cliente
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Clasificacion_Cliente K ON K.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente=C.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente
END
GO
```

**Ejemplo de datos retornados**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En C# estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

**METODO PARA TRAER LOS DATOS**

```
//TRAE LISTADO CLIENTES
        public List<Cliente_G> ListadoClientesAll(string cnn)
        {
            try
            {
                var lista = new List<Cliente_G>();

                using (var ctx=new ModelContext(cnn))
                {
                    var spCustom = "EXEC SP_ListaClientesMante";
                    var query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Cliente_G>(spCustom);

                    lista = (from s in query
                            select new Cliente_G
                            {
                                IdCliente = s.IdCliente,
                                Nombre_Cliente = s.Nombre_Cliente,
                                Direccion = s.Direccion,
                                Clasificacion_Cliente = s.Clasificacion_Cliente,
                                Telefono = s.Telefono,
                                UserName = s.UserName,
                                CorreoCliente = s.CorreoCliente,
                                Preventa = s.Preventa,
                                Reparto = s.Reparto
                            }).ToList();

                    return lista;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

**MODELOS DE DATOS**

```
public class Cliente_G
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Clasificacion_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string CorreoCliente { get; set; }
        public string Preventa { get; set; }
        public string Reparto { get; set; }

    }
```

Pero resulta que cuando mando a llamar los datos me salen incompletos, al hacer un breakpoint lo confirmo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En que estoy fallando en el codigo? Como se puede mejorar ambas partes de ser posible? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ListaClientesMante] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT C.ID_Cliente, C.Cliente, C.Direccion, K.Tipo_Cliente, C.Telefono, L.userName, E.Correo, C.Clasificacion, C.CorreoCliente, C.Reparto, C.Preventa, C.NombreCliente
    FROM dbo.Cliente C WITH(INDEX(Cliente_pk))
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Login L ON L.userName=C.ID_Usuario
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CorreoCliente E ON E.ID_Cliente=C.ID_Cliente
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Clasificacion_Cliente K ON K.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente=C.ID_Clasificacion_Cliente
END
GO
```

Como no sé cuál es la estructura de tu base de datos, ni de tus tablas, ahi te va la consulta, básicamente falta traer definir los datos del SELECT.